# Hive FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near ''macaddress'' 'CHAR' '(' in column specification

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming

I've tried running `hive -v -f sqlfile.sql`

Here is the content of the file

```sql
CREATE TABLE UpStreamParam (
'macaddress' CHAR(50),
'datats' BIGINT,
'cmtstimestamp' BIGINT,
'modulation' INT,
'chnlidx'   INT,
'severity' BIGINT,
'rxpower'  FLOAT,
'sigqnoise' FLOAT,
'noisedeviation'  FLOAT,
'prefecber'  FLOAT,
'postfecber'  FLOAT,
'txpower'  FLOAT,
'txpowerdrop' FLOAT,
'nmter'  FLOAT,
'premtter'  FLOAT,
'postmtter'  FLOAT,
'unerroreds'  BIGINT,
'corrected'  BIGINT,
'uncorrectables'  BIGINT)
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY","orc.bloom.filters.columns"="macaddress")
PARTITIONED BY ('cmtsid' CHAR(50),' date' INT)
LOCATION '/usr/hive/warehouse/UpStreamParam' ;
```

And i'm getting the following error:

> FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near ''macaddress'' 'CHAR' '(' in column specification

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, the column name must be surrounded by `` ` `` (backticks), not  `'` (single quote).

Therefore you have to replace `'macaddress'` to `` `macaddress` ``, as well as all other column names.

Second, the order of `STORED AS` and `TBLPROPERTIES` and `PARTITIONED BY` and `LOCATION` is wrong.
The correct order is `PARTITIONED BY`, `STORED AS`, `LOCATION`, `TBLPROPERTIES`.

See the hive language manual for detail.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable

So the correct code is

```sql
CREATE TABLE UpStreamParam (
`macaddress` CHAR(50),
`datats` BIGINT,
`cmtstimestamp` BIGINT,
`modulation` INT,
`chnlidx`   INT,
`severity` BIGINT,
`rxpower`  FLOAT,
`sigqnoise` FLOAT,
`noisedeviation`  FLOAT,
`prefecber`  FLOAT,
`postfecber`  FLOAT,
`txpower`  FLOAT,
`txpowerdrop` FLOAT,
`nmter`  FLOAT,
`premtter`  FLOAT,
`postmtter`  FLOAT,
`unerroreds`  BIGINT,
`corrected`  BIGINT,
`uncorrectables`  BIGINT)
PARTITIONED BY (`cmtsid` CHAR(50), `date` INT)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION '/usr/hive/warehouse/UpStreamParam'
TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY","orc.bloom.filters.columns"="macaddress");
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. 
Is there any other way accessing the tables rather than using hive cli each time? Let's say that i want to integrate into my code so each time i would  need to execute `hive -e "my query"`

Comment: @user3502786 you can search the web for keyword such as 'hive client' or 'hive webui' https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

Comment: without added quotes(') it will work and char(50) is not working instead of them we can use string.

Comment: just fyi: date is a reserved keyword in hql. so we need to wrap it with `` if using in column names.