# Error while creating table in Hive

Tags: hive

I am new to hadoop. I need a help regarding error encountered in Hive while creating a new table. I have gone through this [Hive FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near ''macaddress'' 'CHAR' '(' in column specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191404/hive-failed-parseexception-line-20-cannot-recognize-input-near-macaddress)

My question: Is it necessary to write a location of the table in the script? because I am  writing table location at starting and I am afraid about writing the location because it should not disturb my rest of the databases by any mulfunction operation.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE meta_statistics.tank_items (
   shop_offers_history_before bigint,
   shop_offers_temp bigint,
   videos_distinct_temp bigint,
   deleted_temp bigint,
   t_stamp timestamp )
   CLUSTERED BY (
   tank_items_id)
   INTO 8 BUCKETS
   ROW FORMAT SERDE
   TBLPROPERTIES (transactional=true)
   STORED AS ORC;
```

The error I am getting is-

> ParseException line 1:3 cannot recognize input near 'TBLPROPERTIES'
>   '(' 'transactional'

What would be the other possibilities of errors and how can I remove those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your create query. Error which you have shared says that hive cannot recognize input near `'TBLPROPERTIES'`.

**Solution:**

As per hive syntax, the key value passed in  `TBLPROPERTIES` should be in double quotes. it should be like this: `TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true")`

So if I correct your query it will be:

```
 CREATE TABLE meta_statistics.tank_items ( 
     shop_offers_history_before bigint, 
     shop_offers_temp bigint, 
     videos_distinct_temp bigint, 
     deleted_temp bigint, 
     t_stamp timestamp 
  ) CLUSTERED BY (tank_items_id) INTO 8 BUCKETS 
    ROW FORMAT SERDE TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true") STORED AS ORC;
```

Execute above query, then if you get any other syntax error them make sure that the order of `STORED AS , CLUSTERED BY , TBLPROPERTIES` is as per the hive syntax.

Refer this for more details:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable

Comment: Hello Reena, I have created a new database meta_statistics and excecute d corrected query and facing another error SemanticException [Error 10002]: Invalid column reference but I don't understand which column reference the error is and what to do with that? thanks for your time

Comment: Yes I got it ! I just replaced cluster column reference with other existing column reference and it works fine now. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1) `ROW FORMAT SERDE` -> you should pass some serde

2) `TBLPROPERTIES` key value should be in double quotes

3) if you give `CLUSTERED BY` value should be there in the columns given

replace as follows

```
CREATE TABLE meta_statistics.tank_items ( shop_offers_history_before bigint, shop_offers_temp bigint, videos_distinct_temp bigint, deleted_temp bigint, t_stamp timestamp ) CLUSTERED BY (shop_offers_history_before) INTO 8 BUCKETS ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'  STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true");
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hello Nirmal, I have implemented what you have suggested but shwoing me another type of error-  ParseException line 40:20 mismatched input 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' expecting StringLiteral near 'SERDE' in serde format specification

Comment: I also have change the postion of "stored as ORC" and "tblproperties" and got error Database does not exist: meta_statistics. So need to create the database or use another database. Thanks a lot.